# Square Root of Symmetric Block Matrix

Tags: symmetric-matrices, block-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

Let $ X\in\mathbb{R}^{(N+1)n}, U\in\mathbb{R}^{Nm}$ be two random variables, with $N,n,m >0$ positive integers.
The covariances of $X$ and $U$ are $\Sigma_{X} = (I + BK)\mathcal{S}(I + BK)^\intercal$ and $\Sigma_U = K\mathcal{S} K^\intercal$, respectively, and the cross-covariance between $X$ and $U$ is $\Sigma_{XU} = (I + BK)\mathcal{S}K^\intercal$, where $\mathcal{S} \in\mathbb{R}^{(N+1)n\times (N+1)n}, K\in\mathbb{R}^{Nm\times (N+1)n}, B \in\mathbb{R}^{(N+1)n\times Nm}$.
For reference, all covariance matrices are positive definite.
I am interesting in finding the square root matrix of the *combined* random vector $Z := [X^\intercal, U^\intercal]^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}^{(N+1)n + Nm}$, that is, $\Sigma_{Z}^{1/2}$.

For $X$ and $U$ individually, it is very simple to the find the square root matrix, that is, matrices $L$ and $M$ such that $LL^\intercal = \Sigma_X$ and $MM^\intercal = \Sigma_U$.
It is clear that

$$
L = (I + BK)\mathcal{S}^{1/2} \quad \textrm{and} \quad M = K\mathcal{S}^{1/2},
$$

where I am assuming that $\mathcal{S}^{1/2}$ can be easily computed (via Cholesky decomposition).
I am struggling, though, to compute $\Sigma_{Z}^{1/2}$.
The random vector $Z$ has the covariance matrix

$$
\Sigma_{Z} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
(I + BK)\mathcal{S}(I + BK)^\intercal & (I + BK)\mathcal{S} K^\intercal \\
K\mathcal{S}(I+BK)^\intercal & K\mathcal{S}K^\intercal
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

However, I am not sure how to find a matrix $P$ such that $PP^\intercal = \Sigma_{Z}$, due to the presence of the cross-covariance terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this problem:

$$
\Sigma_{Z} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I + BK \\
K
\end{bmatrix}
\mathcal{S}
\begin{bmatrix}
(I + BK)^\intercal & K^\intercal
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the decomposition. From here, it's straightforward to compute the square root matrix, i.e.,

$$
\Sigma_{Z}^{1/2} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I + BK \\
K
\end{bmatrix}
\mathcal{S}^{1/2},
$$
which satisfies $\Sigma_{Z}^{1/2}(\Sigma_{Z}^{1/2})^\intercal = \Sigma_{Z}$.